# Prevent MacBook from waking automatically while it is kept in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Is it possible to prevent my MacBook from waking automatically from sleep mode unless I manually intervene by opening the lid or touching the keyboard/using the mouse?

I have set it up to announce the time every 30 minutes. When I close the lid to put it in sleep mode, I still hear the time announcement, even if it's during late night. I expect my MacBook to be sleeping when the lid is closed but that's not the case.

Sometimes, when I open the lid, my MacBook is really hot — I assume it was working or woke up somehow. Again, I would expect it to be sleeping instead of doing some work when the lid is closed.

Both cases happen when the power cable is plugged in.

I don't have any additional hardware connected to the laptop: no monitors, no mouse, no keyboard, etc.

I'd like to set up my machine like this if it's possible: Whenever the lid is closed it goes into 100% sleep mode, no Power Nap, no email checks, no battery power wasting for tasks I don't need. Just plain sleep.

Comment: Along with turning off Power Nap, can you ensure that you don't have any specialized utility app installed and running which is programmed to [prevent MacBook from sleeping when the lid is closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248273/how-to-prevent-macbook-from-sleeping-when-the-lid-is-closed)?

Comment: Do you perhaps have Caffeine running without knowing it.

Comment: I don't want PowerNap either, but I've given up on getting rid of it.